# To get the XMPP message in the background without using persistent Service

Tags: android, android-service, smack, asmack

I am trying to build an IM using Smack Library. I did it correctly and its working fine in foreground and I could start a STICKY service which can look for the message in the background. My issue is that I don't want a persistent service in the background, because it will eat up the battery of the android device, instead I want some broadcast to be fired up when the XMPP message comes with some events.

Is there any way I could achieve this? I have tried looking for example with the search term and I found nothing so I did not achieve any sort in this particular context so does not have any relevant code.

Comment: while your application is going on background u can "stopself()" method call inside "onTaskRemoved()" method inside service class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all depends on what you want to archive.

If you need fast direct message arrival when the 2 clients are online, I think that the persistent service is the only solution with smack xmpp . With solid code development it should not eat up much battery...

If you don't really care if the message arrives after 2 minutes for example, you should use an intentservice (connect/get messages/disconnect) & a timer (e.g. every 2 mins) as long as the app is running.

What you describe (some broadcast to be fired up when the message comes) is more similar to PUSH mechanisms like Google Cloud Messaging...

Comment: I want the messages quickly as it will be a chat client. I have tried Smack and its working well and I can implement it using  a service and its working well as well however I want something which should not run in the background. As you have advised to use a timer to check for message lets say every two minutes then there will be a chance of missing messages as well cause in between those 2 minutes where we are not checking there may be a message..what should I do then???

Comment: If you really do not want to have a service running in the background, then you should have a look at Google Cloud Messaging...

Comment: That I tried and finds it unpredictable. Its good to use it for Push Notification but not for chat..I also tried the Upstream Messaging(CCS) however they say it has to be applied and its fully supported from Android KK so that cant be used in my case!!!

Comment: You have 2 clear choises: (1) use smack with persistent service (2) use something PUSH-like, like gcm, parse etc.   Good luck to your app

Comment: Keep in mind that somehow a persistent service has to exist for your functionality to work. By using gsm, this persistent service executes in google play services, not your app. By using Parse, your application seems to always execute to the user (as the parse lib code waits for push messages). By using aSmack with a service you have the full control of the resources and it is not so bad idea